# Print longest line out of a file Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io, line

I am trying to print the longest line in the file 'words', which is a file with a list of words (each in a new line). 
With this code below, I get it to print each line that was longer than the previous compared to. However, I need it to just print the longest line out of the whole file.

I am still new with Ruby and I can't seem to find the answer on google.

```
max = 0
IO.foreach('words') do |line|
    if line.length > max
        max = line.length  
        print line 
    end
end
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A more concise and Ruby-esque way of doing this would be

```
puts IO.foreach('words').max_by(&:length)
```

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to keep track of the longest line, and only print when done.

Something like this:

```
max = 0
longest = ""
IO.foreach('words') do |line|
    if line.length > max
        max = line.length  
        longest = line 
    end
end
print longest
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I did not know we could have something like `longest = "" ` Thank you!